# Formatting with 2 decimal places (NSDecimalNumber)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, number-formatting

I have an extension in my NSDecimalNumber

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    func format(f: String) -> String {
        return String(format: "%\(f)f", self)
    }
}
```

This should allow me to do the following:

```
var price = 34.2499999

price.format(f: ".2") // 35.25
```

Instead, I get 0.00 in my `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
func configureCell(_ item: Item) {

        self. item = item

        nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        priceLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        nameLabel.text = self. item.name.capitalized
        priceLabel.text = "£\(self. item.price!.format(f: ".2"))"

    }
```

I would like to format it with the real price showing two decimal places instead of a random number. All prices are retrieved from a database and are accurate with only 2 decimal places.

For some reason, when I remove the formatting from the extension, I get more decimals where I only have 2 in the database. Why is this happening and how is it solved?

Comment: You have defined an extension of  `NSDecimalNumber`, that will not be applied to a `Double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably due a type conversion under the hood. You can always format the price with a `NSNumberFormatter` to give you the correct currency format instead of doing a string format like so

```
extension NSNumber {
    func toCurrency() -> String? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return numberFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Also remember to initialize a `NSDecimalNumber` with your price variable before calling this extension method

Comment: There's a return missing in the function

Comment: It works perfectly, just needed to change the currency :) Thanks!

Comment: There is an error in this code. `numberFormatter.string` returns an optional `String`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @PeterSchorn! I've updated the code

Comment: @cjrieck No problem.